# iterate an Array List in Struts2

Tags: list, struts2, loops

I have a list and reach entry in the list is an other list.  I have this list ready with me, all i want to do is to display it through jsp.

How do I iterate a list which return one more list.

Any help is appreciated.

Regards,
Senny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See: http://struts.apache.org/2.0.11/docs/iterator.html

Following should work, not tested:

```
<s:iterator value="parentList">
    <s:iterator>
        <s:property/>
    <s:iterator>
</s:iterator>
```

The inner iterator I think should use the current value pushed onto the stack by the outer iterator. The S2 property tag does the same.

If you have more complicated nesting, you add the *var* property to the parent iterator with a value. This value then becomes the name of the pushed value inside the iterator.

An example of this:

```
<s:iterator value="parentList" var="referencedAs">
    <s:iterator value="referencedAs">
        <s:property/>
    <s:iterator>
</s:iterator>
```